# Did Bran know that important fact about greensight?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In s06e05 we saw that

> Greensight isn't just a 3D movie - it can interact with watcher/visitor and even harm him. In s06e04, Bran thought that Ned was able to hear him, but Raven said nothing about it. In s06e05, it became clear that Raven knew that touching the White Walker in the greensight is extremely dangerous.

Was Bran warned about that important fact?

Comment: Funny fact: site proposed that question " How did Agent Smith know that Morpheus contacted Neo?" can contain the answer to my question. AI recognised the similarity between the Matrix and the Greensight :D

Comment: Not really relevant at this point in Show-Book schism but TEC said "I have my own ghosts, Bran. A brother that I loved (Daemon/Daeron), a brother that I hated (Aegor), a woman that I desired (Shiera). Through the trees, I see them still, but no word of mine has ever reached them. The past remains the past. We can learn from it, but we cannot change it."

Answer (score 6):

Bran was never warned about that important fact on screen. Its viewer speculation whether he was warned off screen. I think Morpheus from the Matrix put it best.

> What happened, happened and could not have happened any other way

If Bran had been warned, he might not have been branded by the Night King or been shouted at to warg into Wylis (and turned him into Hodor).

If that hadn't happened, Hodor wouldn't have lost his mind and ended up with them at the Tree.

The Raven knew what Bran had to do and encouraged him at critical moment.

Comment: "The ink is dry" I believe is what Raven said.

Answer (score 1):

Dream marking is a relatively commonly used fantasy element. It is also used in Sword of Truth series. The palantir scene in the lotr also resembles this scene. It was a good scene but I do not believe we have enough information to make interpretations.

Even though you left out a-song-of-fire-and-ice tag, we have some information in the books.

> When Bran tried to talk to his father, Brynden said "He heard a whisper on the wind, a rustling amongst the leaves. You cannot speak to him, try as you might."

So I do not believe Bran cannot interact with anyone from the past. In my opinion, Bran being harmed/marked is only due to the magical nature of the Night King. It shouldn't happen with anyone non-magical, and we really have little information about it whatsoever.

Comment: I left out a-song-of-fire-and-ice tag because I thought that in the books there were no successful interactions between Bran and people/things in Greensight. And I'm not sure, will Greensight in the books be as dangerous as in series

Comment: The danger as far as I know is the toll on the greenseer, like Jojen having epilepsy attacks. I think the danger was not due to greenseeing, but due to the magic of the Night's King.

Comment: Gotta -1 this because the querent deliberately left out [tag:a-song-of-ice-and-fire] and the two stories are clearly divergent at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Bran was actually told the opposite though that is about the past and it's not clear if when Bran met the Night King if that was the past or present.

> Bran Stark: He heard me.
>   Three Eyed Raven: Maybe. Maybe he heard the wind.
>   Bran Star: He heard me.
>   Three Eyed Raven: T**he past is already written. The ink is dry.**
>   <sub>Game of Thrones, Season 6 Episode 3, "Oathbreaker"</sub>

It's possible that the Three Eyed Raven didn't know that Bran could interact during his greensight, knew but chose not to tell or it was the Night King's powers that caused the event to happen, we simply don't know.